# クラッシュの原因が分からない

Tags: ios, swift3

iOSアプリをApp Storeの審査に提出したところ、We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch.との理由でリジェクトされました。
実機で確認したところクラッシュが再現できないので、Appleから送られてきたクラッシュログを読んでいるのですが、何が原因で起動時にクラッシュするのかが分かりません。
実機はiPhone OS 10.3.3です。

MyAppというのが、私がつくっているアプリの名前になります。

```
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.3 (14G60)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1840befe0 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x182b20538 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1840bef28 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
3   Foundation                      0x184b25104 -[NSBundle initWithURL:] + 104
4   Foundation                      0x184b25088 +[NSBundle bundleWithURL:] + 48
5   MyApp                   0x10043c824 0x1000e4000 + 3508260
6   MyApp                   0x10043c7ac 0x1000e4000 + 3508140
7   MyApp                   0x100224f30 0x1000e4000 + 1314608
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x182f769a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x182f776cc dispatch_once_f + 56
10  MyApp                   0x100224e6c 0x1000e4000 + 1314412
11  MyApp                   0x1002214b4 0x1000e4000 + 1299636
12  MyApp                   0x1002213f0 0x1000e4000 + 1299440
13  MyApp                   0x100222888 0x1000e4000 + 1304712
14  MyApp                   0x1002138b4 0x1000e4000 + 1243316
15  MyApp                   0x100213020 0x1000e4000 + 1241120
16  MyApp                   0x100212e60 0x1000e4000 + 1240672
17  MyApp                   0x1000ea83c 0x1000e4000 + 26684
18  MyApp                   0x1000eb2a4 0x1000e4000 + 29348
19  UIKit                           0x18a1e9b04 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1036
20  UIKit                           0x18a1e96e0 -[UIViewController view] + 28
21  UIKit                           0x18a1eff60 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 76
22  UIKit                           0x18a1ed3fc -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 272
23  UIKit                           0x18a25ee68 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 48
24  UIKit                           0x18a467430 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3632
25  UIKit                           0x18a46ce24 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1684
26  UIKit                           0x18a4818b0 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.3147 + 48
27  UIKit                           0x18a46a0b8 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168
28  FrontBoardServices              0x185c68884 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
29  FrontBoardServices              0x185c686f0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 176
30  FrontBoardServices              0x185c68aa0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
31  CoreFoundation                  0x18406d42c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
32  CoreFoundation                  0x18406cd9c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
33  CoreFoundation                  0x18406a9a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 744
34  CoreFoundation                  0x183f9ada4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
35  UIKit                           0x18a253fc8 -[UIApplication _run] + 652
36  UIKit                           0x18a24ec9c UIApplicationMain + 208
37  MyApp                   0x1000ec948 0x1000e4000 + 35144
38  libdyld.dylib                   0x182fa959c start + 4


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001830b9014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183183264 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018302d9c4 abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182af91b0 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182b12c04 default_unexpected_handler() + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182b20820 _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182b0f5d4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182b0f640 std::terminate() + 60
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182f769b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 36
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182f776cc dispatch_once_f + 56
10  MyApp                   0x0000000100224e6c 0x1000e4000 + 1314412
11  MyApp                   0x00000001002214b4 0x1000e4000 + 1299636
12  MyApp                   0x00000001002213f0 0x1000e4000 + 1299440
13  MyApp                   0x0000000100222888 0x1000e4000 + 1304712
14  MyApp                   0x00000001002138b4 0x1000e4000 + 1243316
15  MyApp                   0x0000000100213020 0x1000e4000 + 1241120
16  MyApp                   0x0000000100212e60 0x1000e4000 + 1240672
17  MyApp                   0x00000001000ea83c 0x1000e4000 + 26684
18  MyApp                   0x00000001000eb2a4 0x1000e4000 + 29348
19  UIKit                           0x000000018a1e9b04 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1036
20  UIKit                           0x000000018a1e96e0 -[UIViewController view] + 28
21  UIKit                           0x000000018a1eff60 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 76
22  UIKit                           0x000000018a1ed3fc -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 272
23  UIKit                           0x000000018a25ee68 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 48
24  UIKit                           0x000000018a467430 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3632
25  UIKit                           0x000000018a46ce24 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1684
26  UIKit                           0x000000018a4818b0 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.3147 + 48
27  UIKit                           0x000000018a46a0b8 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168
28  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000185c68884 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
29  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000185c686f0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 176
30  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000185c68aa0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
31  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018406d42c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
32  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018406cd9c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
33  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018406a9a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 744
34  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183f9ada4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
35  UIKit                           0x000000018a253fc8 -[UIApplication _run] + 652
36  UIKit                           0x000000018a24ec9c UIApplicationMain + 208
37  MyApp                   0x00000001000ec948 0x1000e4000 + 35144
38  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000182fa959c start + 4
```

Comment: スタックトレースの中で、自アプリ名が比較的浅い階層に出てくる場合はそれがかなりのヒントになります。今回の場合、`5   MyApp`の行です。その直上に`4   Foundation ... +[NSBundle bundleWithURL:] ...`というのが見えます。Swiftでは`Bundle.init(url:)`に当たるメソッド(Swiftではイニシャライザ)です。あなたのコードの中でそのイニシャライザを使用している部分はありませんか?